# detect filled rectangles in image

Tags: c++, opencv

How to detect filled rectangles in image?

I need to get the bounding box for the 4 white (filled with white) rectangles in the right side of the image, but not the big rectangle in the middle with a white outline

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can isolate each contour by drawing the contour on a mask. Then you can use that mask on the image to calculate the average color. A high average indicates that the contour contains mostly white, so it is likely a contour you want.

Result:

[image]

Code:

```
    import numpy as np 
    import cv2
    #load the image
    img = cv2.imread("form.png") 
    # create grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    #Find contours (external only):  
    im, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(gray, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)  
    #draw contours on original image
    for cnt in contours:
        # disregard small contours cause by logo and noise
        if cv2.contourArea(cnt) > 10000:
            #isolate contour and calculate average pixel value
            mask = np.zeros(gray.shape[:2],np.uint8)
            cv2.drawContours(mask,[cnt],0,255,-1)
            mean_val = cv2.mean(gray,mask = mask)
            # a high value indicates the contour contains mostly white, so draw the contour (I used the boundingRect)
            if mean_val[0] > 200:
                x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
                cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y),(x+w,y+h), (0,0,255), thickness=4)
    # show/save image
    cv2.imshow("Image", mask)
    cv2.imwrite("result.jpg", img)

    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Note: you can also load the image as grayscale and skip creating one, but I used it here so I could draw more obvious red boxes.
Also be aware the code given might not generalize well, but it shows the concept.